# C++ Invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++

I'm developing c++ application there I'm getting the error 
`Invalid use of non-static data member C++`. I have posted all the code which is related The error. I would be very grateful if anyone could point out my stupidity. Thanks!

Const2DCDP.h

```
class Const2DCDP{
public:

    int *ex;

};
```

2DCPDP4.h

```
#include "Const2DCDP.h"

    class CDP{
    }
```

2DCPDP4.cpp

```
#include "2DCDP4.h"

    void CDP::Release()
    {

        if(Const2DCDP::ex != NULL){  // Invalid use of non static data //member 'ex'
            free(ex);
            ex = NULL;
        }      
    }
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. Do you know the difference between static and non-static members?

Comment: I love the naming convention for the files. Very intuitive as to their function. PS: Why are you using `free` in C++ code

Answer (score 4):

The data member (`ex`) you are using is not a static member. So it cannot be called on the class name, you need a class *instance* to use it.

Comment: can you please post  how to use it. it will help others too

Comment: @user3423301 you need to understand basics.  Defining the class doesn't give you an object, it just defines how objects behave.  You'd want to be able to have more than one object of your `Const2DCDP` type, each with a different `ex` value, right?

Answer (score 2):

well, it's pretty clear , CDP has no member function named Release , and ex is not static , meaning you can excess it from an allocated object , not from the class itself